# ServiceStack date deserialization error

Tags: servicestack-text

On ServiceStack.Text version 4.0.38

- ServiceStack.Text.Common.DateTimeSerializer.ParseShortestXsdDateTime("9/10/2015")
  **Works**
- ServiceStack.Text.Common.DateTimeSerializer.ParseShortestXsdDateTime("09/10/2015")
  **Don't work**   Input string was not in a correct format
- ServiceStack.Text.Common.DateTimeSerializer.ParseShortestXsdDateTime("10/10/2015")
  **Don't Work** same error

It may be related to the length of the date, not sure... anyone have any idea of why is failing on the two latest cases... it worked on previous versions...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend sticking with the [one true unambiguous way of storing dates in strings](http://xkcd.com/1179/), i.e:

```
"2015-09-10"
```

Comment: Thanks, just to clarify, correct format should be yyyy-mm-dd so your i.e have to be `2015-09-10`

Comment: @GuillermoLondono ahh yep fixed, copy/paste/tweak brain freeze.